# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n^2} x^n$ with different radii of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Could you give an example of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n^2} x^n$$ that have different radii of convergence?

Comment: Take each $a_{n^2}=0$.

Comment: And what will be $a_{i}$ equal where $i \neq n^2$

Comment: Take $a_n=1$, otherwise.

Comment: Anything other than zero

Comment: I understand what you have in mind. Thank you, very clever.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example (pointed out by [David Mitra](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/18986/david-mitra)) probably is:
$$ a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{cl} 0,& n=m^2, \, m\in \mathbb{N} \\ 1, &\text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. $$

$\sum a_nx^n$ has a radius of convergence $1$ while $\sum a_{n^2}x^n$ converges for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.